# Java Array - NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Here is the code (including both classes):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class SortedArray
{
    public int [] myNums;
    public int sizeOfArray;
    private int userInput;
    public Sort sortedArray;
    public Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void sortedArray()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of values to put in the array:");
        int userInput = input.nextInt();
        myNums = new int [userInput];
        sizeOfArray = userInput;
        for(int i=0;i<userInput;i++)
        {
            Random randomNum =  new Random();
            myNums[i] = randomNum.nextInt(100)+1;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<userInput;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(myNums[i]);
        }
        sortedArray = new Sort(myNums, sizeOfArray);
        sortedArray.publicdisplay();
    } 
}

*******************************************************************************

public class Sort
{
    public int[] array;
    public int sizeOfArray;

    public Sort(int[] oldArray, int sizeOfOldArray)
    {
       sizeOfArray = sizeOfOldArray; 
       for( int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
           array[i] = oldArray[i];
       }
       sort();
    }

    public void publicdisplay()
    { 
       for ( int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
           System.out.println(array[i]);
       }
    }

    private void sort()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfArray; i++)
            {
                if (array[j] < array[i])
                {
                    swap(i,j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void swap(int x, int y)
    {
        int temp = 100;
        temp = array[x];
        array[x] = array[y];
        array[y] = temp;
   }
}
```

The program compiles correctly, however when I run the program and enter the number of values to put in the array, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Sort.<init>(Sort.java:17)
at SortedArray.sortedArray(SortedArray.java:32)
```

It generates the array but does not sort it. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: By the way, your sort() function won't work. You can probably fix it by changing `for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfArray; i++)` to `for (int j = i+1; j < sizeOfArray; j++)`. However, I suggest visiting http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/shell-sort instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NullPointerException being thrown whenever array member is accessed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145728/nullpointerexception-being-thrown-whenever-array-member-is-accessed)

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize your array. Add a line in your constructor:

```
public Sort(int[] oldArray, int sizeOfOldArray)
{
    sizeOfArray = sizeOfOldArray; 
    array = new int[sizeOfOldArray];  // <-- Added this line
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
        array[i] = oldArray[i];
}
```

or even better, use the [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28boolean%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) utility method to do the work for you:

```
public Sort(int[] oldArray, int sizeOfOldArray)
{
    sizeOfArray = sizeOfOldArray; 
    array = Arrays.copyOfRange(oldArray, 0, sizeOfOldArray);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `Sort` class, you have declared an instance variable that is an array, called `array`, but you haven't initialized it, so it's still `null` when you try to access it in your constructor at this line:

```
array[i] = oldArray[i];
```

You need to create your array first.

Comment: Although efficacious, the side effect of this approach is that the array passed in will be sorted. Modifying the array passed in may not be desirable.